# JQuery Value to PHP with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My Website has a Video Player with a random Playlist and a Comments List.

All Comments ever written are loaded. Now I want to change the comments ID, everytime a new Video starts, so that the Site shows only comments for this Video.

The Player is set up in Javascript and has an on Ready Function, that fires an ajax function.
The Comments are set up as a php line with a $value.

This is my code:

```
<div id="comments">
  <?php 
    $commentsID= 3; //Testnumber 3 shows all comments to video 3
    Comment::getCommentSystem($commentsID);
  ?>
</div>

<script>
onReady: function(event) {
videoID; // actual videoID
//and here comes some Ajax Magic, to tell $commentsID = videoID, but how?
// My example doesn't work because it's my first try with Ajax whoohooo
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "index.php",
  data: videoID,
  success: function(videoID){
    $('#comments').empty(); // Clear Testnumber'n stuff
    $(' <?php 
      $commentsID= videoID; 
      Comment::getCommentSystem($commentsID);
    ?>
 ').appendTo('#comments'); // rewrite the comments Div with the videoID
 }
}); 
</script>
```

EDIT:

Now my code looks like this:

```
<div id="comments">
</div>

<script>
[...]
onReady: function(event) {
     videoID; // actual videoID
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "get_comments.php?videoId=" + videoID,
       success: function(response){
         $('#comments').html(response);
   }
     });
}
[...]
</script>
```

get_comments.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include "comment.class.php";
$videoID = $_GET["videoId"];
$comments = Comment::getCommentSystem($videoID);
return($comments);
?>
```

and it produces this:

```
<div id="comments">

  <!-- The Form to add a comment ( always display none ) -->
  <div style="display:none;">
    <div class="comment-post comment-child">
      <form id="addCommentForm" action="" method="post">

<!-- The Form container, that shows the Form comment -->
<!-- ( should be visible - maybe session fail? ) -->
<div class="comment-container" style="display:none;">
  <div class="comment-content">

<!-- all comments to videoID 3 -->
<ul class="comment-list-3">
</div>
```

Comment: `onReady:` ? what is that ? ( *other than an error right from the start* )

Comment: You can't have PHP code in your AJAX success function. And `videoID` in PHP is probably going to give you an error.

Comment: the onReady function is in the video Player, I just snippet the uninteresting things out. And ya, I know, that php cannot stay in AJAX success, but I don't know how to write it correctly, so I've coded something, that doesn't work, but shows, what I want to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not send it index.php, send request to another endpoint like `get_comments.php`,

```
<script>
    onReady: function(event) {
    videoID; // actual videoID
    //and here comes some Ajax Magic, to tell $commentsID = videoID, but how?
    // My example doesn't work because it's my first try with Ajax whoohooo
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "get_comments.php?videoId=" + videoID,
      success: function(response){
        $('.comment-list-3').empty(); // Clear Testnumber'n stuff
        var html = '';
        $.each(response, function(i, item) {
            // Do your html here. I assume, your comment object has a field "text". Update it according too your need
            html += '<div>' + item.text + '</div>';
        });
        $('.comment-list-3').html(html); // rewrite the comments Div with the videoID
     }
    }); 
</script>
```

and in your `get_comments.php`;

```
<?php

$videoID = $_GET["videoId"];
$comments = Comment::getCommentSystem($videoID); // Let say this is array
echo json_encode($comments);
?>
```

Comment: Now I recieve a Fatal error: Class 'Comment' not found in get_comments.php on line 4.
Why is it an array?

Comment: okay, I startet everything in the get_comments.php. Now my Website shows every comment from video ID. That's great - but the answer form isn't visible. Maybe a Session Problem? And under the Comments there stands a "NULL" - what does this means?

Comment: Answer form is in `#comments` div?

Comment: I don't know how to answer it, but in the #comments div, there is only the php line, which gets the commentsystem and the commentID. But this loads the form and the comments. Now I coded your example a bit different:

js: 
success: function(response){
 $('#comments').html(response); 
}

php:
$videoID = $_GET["videoId"];
$comments = Comment::getCommentSystem($videoID);
return($comments);

Comment: Now the "NULL" is gone which came from the json array, right? And only the comments stand under the video player. But I don't get it, why the answer form doesn't show up. In the php I have to start a session and include the comment system classes, so the error doesn't come up. But know I think, that the extra session start let the comment system think, I am a guest without any rights to write. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please post your form on your question also? I can help you if i see your form and comments section

Comment: I edited my question with actual code and what it should produce :)

Comment: I have updated `#comments` to `.comment-list-3`. See my updated unswer and apply

Comment: I've tried it with (.comment-list-'+videoID) but then the whole commentsystem didn't load. So I simply deleted the display css, and that works well, exept the bad feeling that something isn't that save now :D

Comment: What is your save error? and put your save form or js in your question

Comment: It's all fine now, thank you :) I mixed up save and safe, sorry.

Comment: @Doppelherz upvote and confirm will be appreciated :)

Comment: I wish I could, but stackoverflow says I need 15 reputation and I don't know how to get that points :v

Answer (score 0):

As Hüseyin BABAL mentioned you could use $_GET to recieve a video id and then prepare the page. Yuou could store the $_GET value in an attribute (for example: data-video-id="3") so you can read it using JS/jQUery. It is possible to fetch URL parts using JS but it is a bit more difficult.

WARNING: If you work with user input (like $_GET and $_POST) ALWAYS validate input.

Comment: Sure, I assume he is always validating input